# Python class as datastore

Tags: python, attributes, setattr

I'm trying to write a Python class that acts like some sort of datastore. So instead of using a dictionary for example, I want to access my data as *class.foo* and still be able to do all the cool stuff like iterate over it as *for x in dataclass*.

The following is what I came up with:

```
class MyStore(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = {}
        for d in data:
            # Just for the sake of example
            self._data[d] = d.upper()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._data.values().__iter__()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __contains__(self, name):
        return name in self._data

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._data[name]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._data[name]


store = MyStore(['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'])
print "Store items:", [item for item in store]
print "Number of items:", len(store)
print "Get item:", store['foo']
print "Get attribute:", store.foo
print "'foo' is in store:", 'foo' in store
```

And, apparently it works. Hooray! But how do I implement the setting of an attribute correctly? Adding the following ends up in an recursion limit on `__getattr__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self._data[name] = value
```

Reading the docs, I should call the superclass (object) `__setattr__` method to avoid recursion, but that way I can't control my self._data dict.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: why not just add the iteration stuff to a normal object, and use its `__dict__` instead of your dict?

Comment: You can increase the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    super(MyStore, self).__setattr__(name, value)
    self._data[name] = value
```

---

However, you could save yourself a lot of hassle by just subclassing something like `dict`:

```
class MyStore(dict):

    def __init__(self, data):
        for d in data:
            self[d] = d.upper()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

store = MyStore(['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'])
print "Store items:", [item for item in store]
print "Number of items:", len(store)
print "Get item:", store['foo']
print "Get attribute:", store.foo
print "'foo' is in store:", 'foo' in store
store.qux = 'QUX'
print "Get qux item:", store['qux']
print "Get qux attribute:", store.qux
print "'qux' is in store:", 'qux' in store
```

which outputs...

```
Store items: ['eggs', 'foo', 'bar', 'spam']
Number of items: 4
Get item: FOO
Get attribute: FOO
'foo' is in store: True
Get qux item: QUX
Get qux attribute: QUX
'qux' is in store: True
```

Comment: Aha, subclassing dict saves me work indeed. I only had to add the `__iter__` method from the question so I get the values and not the keys when iterating over the class. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, although given that you're creating a `dict`-like structure that has keys and values, it might have made more sense to leave the iteration going over keys and use the already-provided `.itervalues()` method if you want to iterate over values. :)

Comment: Fair enough, but since I'm always interested in the values once the class is created, this saves me to call `.itervalues()`. Your comment made me change the return line to `return self.itervalues()` though, it looks better.